# Euler's relation integral help?

Tags: integration, complex-numbers

I’m having trouble following the equation below:
$$\begin{align} E_{period} & = \int_0^{T_0} \lvert e^{j\omega_0t} \rvert \,dt \\ & = \int_0^{T_0} 1 \cdot dt = T_0 \end{align} $$

I know that $ \cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x) = 1 $, so I'm assuming they are somehow using that identity, but I can't figure out how they get there.

$$e^{j\omega_0t}= \cos{\omega_0t}+j\sin{\omega_0t}$$ 
so

$$\left(e^{j\omega_0t}\right)^2 = \cos^2(\omega_0t) + 2j\cos(\omega_0t)\sin(\omega_0t) - \sin^2(\omega_0t)$$

This is as far as I can get.  I know $2\cos(x)\sin(x) = \sin(2x)$, but I don't think that helps me here.  Really stumped, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you use both $\sin 2x = 2\sin x\cos x$ and $\cos 2x = \cos^2 x-\sin^2 x$, then you get $\left(e^{j\omega_0t}\right)^2 = \cos 2x + j\sin 2x$ which must also be on the unit circle (i.e., of magnitude $1$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$\vert\exp(jwt)\vert^2 = \exp(jwt) \cdot \exp(-jwt).$$

Comment: perfect thanks, that answers my question, but now I've got another haha.  why exactly does the abs(e^(jwt))^2 = e^(jwt) * e^(-jwt)?

Comment: It holds $|z|^2 = z \cdot \bar{z}$ for every complex number. That the complex conjugate of $e^{jwt}$ is  $e^{-jwt}$ follows for example from Euler's identity.

Comment: thanks, I've thought about it a different way too.  I guess |z|^2 = magnitude.  But I can think of it as abs(a+b) = sqrt(a^2 + b^2) = sqrt(cos^2(wt) + sin^2(wt)) = sqrt(1) =  1